# AWS S3 Give group download rights on specified bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've create a user, and put them in a group. The group has the following policy attached to it:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1424542175000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::acme-reports/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When I log in with the user, and attempt to access https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/acme-reports/uploadedFile.txt I get access denied.

Am I wrong in assuming this user group should be able to access the file directly via URL once logged in? Or can they only access files via the AWS management console?

Comment: The login you use to access the console does not automatically apply to an s3 URL. When you download a private file from the s3 console, you will see that it adds authentication parameters to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions specified through IAM policy allows you to access the files only with AWS Console or with AWS S3 API.
If you want to access your files via URL, you need to apply public permissions using the ACL settings or bucket policy.

In order to make your files public using ACL, you need to perform the following steps:

1. Open S3 Management Console https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/
2. Choose your bucket, folder or file, go to "Properties | Permissions | Add more permissions"

You can also apply the Bucket Policy, it provides more flexible way to control your permissions:

1. Open S3 Management Console https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/
2. Choose your bucket, go to "Properties | Edit Bucket Policy"

For more information about bucket policies and ACL permissions, please see the following AWS documentation:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html